# How to stretch a background-image to 100% width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to stretch my background-image over the width of my screen (100%) but can't seem to make this work. It's more visible in this picture to see what I mean: [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXHxZ.jpg) or the website is online aswell: [link](http://student.howest.be/lucas.verhoest/20172018/major2/index.html)

What am I doing wrong?

```css
.footer-img {
  background-image: url(../assets/img/footer-splashes-01.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center bottom;
  /* width: 100%; */
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.container-footer {
  width: 96rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 25rem;
}

footer li {
  height: 8rem;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.social-media {
  padding-top: 5rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="footer-img">
    <div class="container-footer">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Devine</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="social-media">
        <a href="http://www.devine.be"><img src="./assets/img/devine.png" alt="devine" width=50 height=50></a>
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img src="./assets/img/facebook.png" alt="facebook" width=50 height=50></a>
        <a href="http://www.twitter.com"><img src="./assets/img/twitter.png" alt="twitter" width=50 height=50></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Try to use { background-size: cover; }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `background-size: cover;` instead of `background-size: 100% 100%;` to your `.footer-img`

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.footer-img {
  background-image: url(../assets/img/footer-splashes-01.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center bottom;
  /* width: 100%; */
  background-size: cover;
}

.container-footer {
  width: 96rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 25rem;
}

footer li {
  height: 8rem;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.social-media {
  padding-top: 5rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="footer-img">
    <div class="container-footer">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Devine</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="social-media">
        <a href="http://www.devine.be"><img src="./assets/img/devine.png" alt="devine" width=50 height=50></a>
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img src="./assets/img/facebook.png" alt="facebook" width=50 height=50></a>
        <a href="http://www.twitter.com"><img src="./assets/img/twitter.png" alt="twitter" width=50 height=50></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Oh god. Thank you. Didn't think of that... Appreciate it! .

Answer (score 0):

```
.footer-img {
background-image: url(../assets/img/footer-splashes-01.svg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center bottom;
width: 100%;
background-size: cover;
}
```

This would do. just replace the background-size with background-size:cover

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (add to your existing code):

```
.footer-img {
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

You will end-up with something like:
[Example of your result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PMB5.jpg)